# Using gulp-prompt and gulp-ftp together?

Tags: javascript, ftp, gulp

I have an ftp server I used to deploy to with a Grunt task.  I am now using Gulp.

I quickly found gulp-ftp, except it stores the ftp password in the gulpfile... so I then found gulp-prompt which would allow the script to prompt every time. Fine.

However, I'm having issues using them together.  I'm not sure how and where to integrate the ftp task into the password prompt:

```
gulp.task('deploy', function () {
 return gulp.src('build/*')
  .pipe(prompt.prompt({
   type: 'password',
   name: 'pass',
   message: 'Please enter your password'
 }, function(res){
//value is in res.pass
ftp({
  host: 'ftp.mysite.com',
  user: 'mrwonderful',
  pass: res.pass
 });
}))
```

This is obviously wrong, as it throws a whole bunch of indecipherable errors.

Answer (score 2):

I didnt use gulp-prompt before. You now that ftp is not secure way to connect, and your password is send not encrypted? But i make to work gulp-ftp and gulp prompt:

```
gulp.task('deploy', function () {
    return gulp.src('/')//it may be anything
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
    type: 'password',
    name: 'pass',
    message: 'Please enter your password'
    }, function(res){
        gulp.src(['archive.zip'],{ base: './' })//now you have to target what you want to send
        .pipe(ftp({
            host: 'yourhost',
            user: 'youruser',
            pass: res.pass
        }));
    }));
});
```

i recomend you to use scp or ssh to send. And i zip project before i upload and then by ssh i unzip it.